What 'technical grounds' did the Spanish supreme court invoke to not apply the amnesty to Puigdemont?
BBC

There appear to be several motives behind Carles Puigdemont's return to Spain.
Firstly, he wants to pressure the authorities into applying the country's new amnesty law - which withdraws legal action against Catalan nationalists - to him, after the supreme court excluded him from its application on technical grounds.

What 'technical grounds' did the Spanish supreme court invoke to not apply the amnesty to Puigdemont?

As reported here, the Court read the amnesty law to not apply in circumstances where the defendant personally benefitted from the alleged wrong.
Whether that is best categorized as "technical grounds" is not really a legal question.

Don't all accused 'personally benefit' from an amnesty? This could use more elaboration.

@Lookingforloopholes: Read again: the question was whether he personally benefited from the alleged wrong (i.e. the crime he was convicted of, not the amnesty). Presumably they thought the amnesty was for crimes committed solely for political reasons, not crimes committed for personal gain.
